# odoo salesforce integration

Tags: connected-apps

Do we need to buy salesforce license for integrating with it with odoo. And what if i'm using Sandbox account for salesforce. Do i still need to buy the license. Recently i tried connecting salesforce with odoo connector. Was successful with the authorization. But when i try to import or export from odoo to salesforce than the refresh token expires automatically. So, Is this Problem related to License of salesforce account?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using developer org of salesforce then-No License will be needed.
If you want to use any other org like enterprise then the license will be needed.

If you are an Odoo developer maybe you have heard about [salesforce connector](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/connector_salesforce/), in this link you can search or do what needs to happen.

If you want to know regarding access token, please remember salesforce token is going to expire soon may be in 1hour or 1-day maximum. so for API connection we need to generate access token each token.

thanks, hope this will work fine.